# How to detect and remove outliers from each column of pandas dataframe at one go?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas data frame with six columns and i know there are some outliers in each column.So i have these two lines of code which is pretty much doing what i want to do. But it's removing outliers from only one column of the dataframe. so what if i want to remove outliers from each column together??

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'stlines':np.random.normal(size=533)})
df = df[np.abs(df.stlines-df.stlines.mean()) <= (2*df.stlines.std())]
```

what would be the elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your outliers in each column may happen for varying rows(records).  I'd advise you be happy with substituting `np.nan`

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(size=(20, 8)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGH')
)

df

           A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H
0  -2.129724 -1.268466 -1.970500 -2.259055 -0.349286 -0.026955  0.316236  0.348782
1   0.715364  0.770763 -0.608208  0.352390 -0.352521 -0.415869 -0.911575 -0.142538
2   0.746839 -1.504157  0.611362  0.400219 -0.959443  1.494226 -0.346508 -1.471558
3   1.063243  1.062997  0.591860  0.296212 -0.774732  0.831452  1.486976  0.256220
4  -0.899906  0.375085 -0.519501  0.050101  0.949959 -1.033773  0.948247  0.733776
5   1.236118  0.155475 -1.341267  0.162864  1.258253  0.778040  1.341599 -1.636039
6  -0.195368  0.131820  2.069013  0.048729 -1.500564  0.907342  0.029326  0.066119
7  -0.728821 -2.137846  1.402702 -0.017209 -0.071309 -0.533061  1.273899  0.348510
8  -0.920391  0.348579 -0.835074 -0.225377  0.206295 -0.582825 -1.511850  1.633570
9   0.403321  0.992765  0.025249 -1.664999 -1.558044 -0.361630 -1.784971 -0.318569
10 -0.326400 -0.688203  0.506420 -0.386706 -0.368351 -0.293383 -2.086973 -0.807873
11  0.068855 -0.525141  0.745524  0.911930 -0.277785 -0.866313  1.155518  1.421480
12  1.416653 -0.120607  1.367540 -0.811585 -0.205071 -0.450472 -0.993868 -0.084107
13  2.222507  0.668158  0.463331 -0.302869  0.226355 -0.966131  1.015160 -0.329008
14 -1.070002  0.525867  0.616915  0.399136 -0.233075 -0.482919 -1.018142 -1.673869
15  0.058956  0.242391 -0.660237 -0.081101  1.690625  0.296406 -0.938197  0.225710
16 -0.352254  0.170126 -0.943541  0.627847 -0.948773  0.126131  1.162792 -0.492266
17 -0.444413 -0.028003 -0.286051  0.895515 -0.234507  1.005886 -1.350465 -0.959034
18  0.992524 -1.471428  0.270001 -1.197004 -0.324760 -1.383568  0.838075 -1.125205
19  0.024837  0.238895  0.350742 -0.541868 -0.730284  0.113695  0.068872 -0.032520
```

---

### `pandas.DataFrame.mask`

```
df.mask((df - df.mean()).abs() > 2 * df.std())

           A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H
0        NaN -1.268466       NaN       NaN -0.349286 -0.026955  0.316236  0.348782
1   0.715364  0.770763 -0.608208  0.352390 -0.352521 -0.415869 -0.911575 -0.142538
2   0.746839 -1.504157  0.611362  0.400219 -0.959443       NaN -0.346508 -1.471558
3   1.063243  1.062997  0.591860  0.296212 -0.774732  0.831452  1.486976  0.256220
4  -0.899906  0.375085 -0.519501  0.050101  0.949959 -1.033773  0.948247  0.733776
5   1.236118  0.155475 -1.341267  0.162864  1.258253  0.778040  1.341599 -1.636039
6  -0.195368  0.131820  2.069013  0.048729 -1.500564  0.907342  0.029326  0.066119
7  -0.728821       NaN  1.402702 -0.017209 -0.071309 -0.533061  1.273899  0.348510
8  -0.920391  0.348579 -0.835074 -0.225377  0.206295 -0.582825 -1.511850       NaN
9   0.403321  0.992765  0.025249 -1.664999 -1.558044 -0.361630 -1.784971 -0.318569
10 -0.326400 -0.688203  0.506420 -0.386706 -0.368351 -0.293383 -2.086973 -0.807873
11  0.068855 -0.525141  0.745524  0.911930 -0.277785 -0.866313  1.155518  1.421480
12  1.416653 -0.120607  1.367540 -0.811585 -0.205071 -0.450472 -0.993868 -0.084107
13       NaN  0.668158  0.463331 -0.302869  0.226355 -0.966131  1.015160 -0.329008
14 -1.070002  0.525867  0.616915  0.399136 -0.233075 -0.482919 -1.018142 -1.673869
15  0.058956  0.242391 -0.660237 -0.081101       NaN  0.296406 -0.938197  0.225710
16 -0.352254  0.170126 -0.943541  0.627847 -0.948773  0.126131  1.162792 -0.492266
17 -0.444413 -0.028003 -0.286051  0.895515 -0.234507  1.005886 -1.350465 -0.959034
18  0.992524 -1.471428  0.270001 -1.197004 -0.324760 -1.383568  0.838075 -1.125205
19  0.024837  0.238895  0.350742 -0.541868 -0.730284  0.113695  0.068872 -0.032520
```

---

### + `dropna`

If you only want rows for which no outliers exist for any column, you could follow up the above with `dropna`

```
df.mask((df - df.mean()).abs() > 2 * df.std()).dropna()



      A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H
1   0.715364  0.770763 -0.608208  0.352390 -0.352521 -0.415869 -0.911575 -0.142538
3   1.063243  1.062997  0.591860  0.296212 -0.774732  0.831452  1.486976  0.256220
4  -0.899906  0.375085 -0.519501  0.050101  0.949959 -1.033773  0.948247  0.733776
5   1.236118  0.155475 -1.341267  0.162864  1.258253  0.778040  1.341599 -1.636039
6  -0.195368  0.131820  2.069013  0.048729 -1.500564  0.907342  0.029326  0.066119
9   0.403321  0.992765  0.025249 -1.664999 -1.558044 -0.361630 -1.784971 -0.318569
10 -0.326400 -0.688203  0.506420 -0.386706 -0.368351 -0.293383 -2.086973 -0.807873
11  0.068855 -0.525141  0.745524  0.911930 -0.277785 -0.866313  1.155518  1.421480
12  1.416653 -0.120607  1.367540 -0.811585 -0.205071 -0.450472 -0.993868 -0.084107
14 -1.070002  0.525867  0.616915  0.399136 -0.233075 -0.482919 -1.018142 -1.673869
16 -0.352254  0.170126 -0.943541  0.627847 -0.948773  0.126131  1.162792 -0.492266
17 -0.444413 -0.028003 -0.286051  0.895515 -0.234507  1.005886 -1.350465 -0.959034
18  0.992524 -1.471428  0.270001 -1.197004 -0.324760 -1.383568  0.838075 -1.125205
19  0.024837  0.238895  0.350742 -0.541868 -0.730284  0.113695  0.068872 -0.032520
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have multiple columns using `all`

```
df[df.apply(lambda x :(x-x.mean()).abs()<(2*x.std()) ).all(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following:

```
def filter_outliers(df, columns):
    masks = (make_mask(df, column) for column in columns)
    full_mask = np.logical_or.reduce(masks)
    return df[full_mask]

def make_mask(df, column):
    standardized = (df[column] - df[column].mean())/df[column].std()
    return standardized.abs() >= 2
```